# Excel Pivot table formatting and retaining subtotals through expansion

Tags: excel, pivot, filtering, subtotal

I have a spreadsheet with several columns

[image: https://i.imgur.com/tcdv4lU.png]

I created a Pivot table and have monthly totals, as well as rollup by Classification, everything is working great, and I have % of that particular month's total working correctly, by doing a Show Values as % of Parent Total

[image: https://i.imgur.com/LTyGxEa.png]

Where I am lost is when I try to average out column B, for the year. If I do a simple = AVERAGE(B3:B14) Excel works fine, *until I expand the pivots*, and then it breaks because the code no longer references the correct rows. Is there a way to reference only those Pivot table rollups, and retain the average even when you expand the rows?

Comment: Did you mean `Average (B6:B17)`?

Comment: You could use `=GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of Changes",$A$3) / 12` to just get the total and divide by 12.  Does that work, or are you not always dividing by 12 months?

Comment: @Profex correct, when I first wrote the code it was 3 cells up. Its just an artifact of me messing with it, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Profex that GETPIVOTDATA will work for any situation where I need to average for the year, but when I get to a 4 month average, for any 4 month period the user would pick, what would the syntax be there? It breaks when I try it for changing periods.